# Authorize.net DPM Plugin Error 14

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, authorize.net

I'm trying to use the Authorize.net plugin for WooCommerce.  When the credit card information is submitted it shows the error message:

> 3,2,14,The referrer, relay response or receipt link URL is invalid.,,P,0,,,400.00,,auth_capture,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,37DB835B672A8FA0CE961F2E3FFD4068,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,788,wc_order_533062c179ac4

I've already made sure the redirect (receipt) URL in the Authorize.net settings is empty, and have double checked the transaction key and API login ID, which are both correct.

Since all the Authorize.net settings seem correct, is it possible this error is being caused by something on the Wordpress end?

Any help appreciated.